# Can I see the initial look of Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

Is the current look of [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) the same as it was when launched? I know there should be lot many changes and updates may have happened during the years. But how exactly the look changed (you may call it a "theme" or a "template")? If so, can someone show me the old version of it? I am asking this because I believe many of the active users are here from the day 1.

Comment: http://web.archive.org/web/20090611080330/http://stackoverflow.com/ <- seems about the earliest version that actually loads properly

Comment: @Blorgbeard - I'm not getting and CSS loading for that version

Comment: @ChrisF Odd, [it seems to work for me](http://i.stack.imgur.com/oXH5Q.png).

Comment: @JeremyBanks Odd, it works for me now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taken from [What did the ORIGINAL StackOverflow look like?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21657/what-did-the-original-stackoverflow-look-like)

> [image]

... or even...

> [image]

Comment: I was going to add an answer that stated that the design hadn't changed that much :) How wrong could I have been!

Comment: @ChrisF: The question quality doesn't seem to have changed much though ;).